# How to display an AlertDialog after taking a picture from camera with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

First of all I prefer to mention that I am newbie with Flutter, so I apologize if my question seems to be a basic one.

How can I display an pop-up just after using the camera.
In this pop-up I want to add the photo that was just taken.

I am trying to create a function that opens a pop-up after using the camera. Unfortunately, my code opens the pop-up before and does not allow me to keep the pop-up closed if the photo is not validated.

In other words, I want to display the photo validated by the user in a pop-up. If the user doesn't validate the photo, the popup stays closed.

Is there a simple way?

Thx a lot for your help !!

Here my code :

````
import 'package:etat_des_lieux/datarooms.dart';
import 'package:etat_des_lieux/room.dart';
import 'package:etat_des_lieux/styles/inventory_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class InventoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final color;

  const InventoryPage({super.key, required this.color});

  @override
  InventoryPageState createState() => InventoryPageState();
}

class InventoryPageState extends State<InventoryPage> {

  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  File? getImage;
  int index = 0;
  int room = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;

    List<Room> rooms = DataRooms().listeDataRooms;
    final Room room = rooms[index];

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Etape N°${index + 1} / ${rooms.length} : ${room.room}",
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: widget.color,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          elevation: 10,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            room.getImage(),
                            height: height / 3,
                            width: width * 0.9,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )),
                        InventoryText(text: room.inventory, title: room.inventoryTitle),
                        Divider(height: 30, thickness: 0.5, color: widget.color),
                        InventoryText(text: room.damages, title: room.damagesTitle),
                        Container(
                          width: width/2,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: width/10),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                            ),
                              onPressed: () {
                              useCamera(ImageSource.camera);
                              showImage();
                              },
                              child: Row (
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: const [
                                  Text(
                                      "Prenez votre photo"
                                  ),
                                  Icon (Icons.camera_alt,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                ],
                              )

                          ),
                        )
                  ],
                ),
            )
        ),

    );

  }

  Future<void> showImage({ title,  image}) async {
    String title;
    String image;
    String path = "image/$getImage";
    if (getImage == null) {
    } else {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return  SimpleDialog(
              children: [
                (getImage == null) ? "" : Image.file(getImage!), // here the error : error: The element type 'Object' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [etat_des_lieux] lib/inventory_page.dart:108)
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }

  Future useCamera(ImageSource source) async {
    XFile? xFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (xFile != null){
      setState(() {
        getImage = File(xFile.path);
      });
    }
  }


}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your onPressed function is not async and you are not waiting for the camera to capture the photo, remove calling showCamera

```
  onPressed: () {
         useCamera(ImageSource.camera);
         //showImage();
   },
```

You can call showImage once the image is captured in the function useCamera function

```
Future useCamera(ImageSource source) async {
    XFile? xFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (xFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        getImage = File(xFile.path);
      });
   showImage(image: getImage);
  }
}
```